# how to substring and extract a dynamic content

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have a string which loads on the page based on the success and failure search results. If the search case is success then my output table will have a string like

```
Search Results - 31 Items Found (Debug Code: 4b50016efc3a1ad93502)
```

or if my search results fail, then the output table will display a string either:

```
Search Results - No data found (Debug Code: 4b50016efc3a1ad93502)
Search Results - 0 Items Found (Debug Code: 4b50016efc3a1ad93502)
Search Results - An Exception Occurred (Debug Code: 4b50016efc3a1ad93502)
```

depending on the input conditions.

I want to extract the Debug Code value and pass on to other scenario to validate further. I know I can use `substring()` to extract the Debug Code, but its position in the string is not constant; it varies based on the input conditions, however Debug code will be at last.

How can I extract the Debug Code value (eg `4b50016efc3a1ad93502`) for all scenarios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex to capture and return the target code:

```
String debugCode = output.replaceAll(".*Debug Code: (\\w+).*|.*", "$1");
```

What's happening here?

The regex `.*Debug Code: (\\w+).*` matches the entire string, and captures (with brackets) the target text using `\\w+`, which means "one or more 'letter' characters" ('letters' included digits). The replacement string `$1` means "group 1" - the first captured group. Because the entire input is matched, this operation effectively *replaces* the whole input with the captured group, so returns just the target text.

So what happens if the input doesn't have a debug code?

The extra `|.*` at the end of the regex means "or 'anything'", so the regex will match the entire input even if there it doesn't have a debug code, but captured group 1 will still exist, but it will be empty, so the operation returns the blank string.

Examples:

```
String output1 = "Results - 0 Items Found (Debug Code: 4b50016efc3a1ad93502)";
String output2 = "something else";

String code1 = output1.replaceAll(".*Debug Code: (\\w+).*|.*", "$1"); // "4b50016efc3a1ad93502"
String code2 = output2.replaceAll(".*Debug Code: (\\w+).*|.*", "$1"); // ""
```

You don't have to use `"|.*"`, but you don't have it, the entire string will be returned if the input doesn't have the 'debug code' format.

Comment: Yes, it works exactly for my case. But could not understand what exactly this "$1" does. Can you please explain?

Comment: I think that `output1` should be `"Results - 0 Items Found ( Debug Code: 4b50016efc3a1ad93502)"` and for completeness I think it should be mentioned that the result of `replaceAll` should be stored as Strings are immutable?

Comment: @Bohemian, I think i get most of the idea. but the thing i did not get is, when the regex matches entire string and captures the text with `\\w+`, it will capture the code along with the last bracket. But when it is outputting, how did it leaves the last bracket? Sorry if i miss any, please help me understand this.

Comment: @Bohemian, ok i get it. because its regex nature of `\\w+`. Thank you. i get the idea now and thanks for the help. I accepted the answer.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Answer updated. Thanks non-gender-specific-sibling!

Answer (score 0):

A java String is invariant. No matter how you get a String, its contents will not change.

For example

```
String s = "the way we were";
String t = s.substring(4, 6);   // t = "way"
s = "abcdefghijk";
```

s is a new String, but t is unchanged